# Do we know the date of death of Shammai Hazaken?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, tannaim

Do we know the Hebrew date of his death?

Comment: Seems unlikely. Do you have a reason to suspect we would?

Answer (score 7):

[Toldos Tanaim Vamoraim - page 286](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43958&st=&pgnum=286&hilite=) says that there is no record of his death anywhere, however he outlived Hillel based on a Gemara in Bava Basra 133b.